# get shell message into gtk msgBox

Tags: c, gtk

in c programm with gtk interface, i have this instruction for copying file,

```
execl("/bin/cp","cp","-i",path,dest,NULL);/*copy*/
```

i want that the confirmation cp -i message to be redirected from the shell to i gtk msgbox even the answer (yes/no) by the box buttons

this is the gtk msgBox i tried:

```
    GtkWidget* dialog;
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
    "Rennomer fichier existant", 
    GTK_WINDOW(window), 
    GTK_DIALOG_MODAL, 
    GTK_STOCK_OK,GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
    GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
    NULL); 
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(lancer_boite);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(GTK_DIALOG(dialog)->vbox), pEntry, TRUE, FALSE, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is of course doable, but it's going to be awkward.

Basically you should look into using [glib's subprocess-spawning API](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) to run the shell command, and then of course you have to parse the output and present it in a dialog. When the user clicks a button in the dialog, you need to map that back to a textual response and send it to the subprocess.

It's way easier to just implement the copying using (again) [glib's GIO API](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-copy).

"Shelling out" is not very common in C, since it's so awkward to integrate.

If you must do this without further library support, look into [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to create a pair of pipes yourself, and set those up to stdin/stdout of the child before calling `exec()`.

Comment: yes but it's an OS exercise , that's why i must use basics codes. where can i found an example please, it will bee faster